# Kann man auch für etwas nicht Aktuelles das Perfekt benutzen?

Tags: perfect-tense

Kann ich das das Perfekt verwenden, wenn ich über ein totes Tier oder einen toten Menschen spreche? Zum Beispiel:

> Meine Katze hat mich immer so glücklich gemacht.
>   Dieser Mann hat sich in dieser Stadt etabliert.

Wegen des Englischen bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Bearbeitung:
Ich habe gemeint, dass der zweite Satz so lauten würde:

> Dieser Mann hat diese Stadt gegründet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im Deutschen ist das Perfekt eine Vergangenheitsform. Es wird beim Sprechen anstelle des hauptsächlich schriftlich verwendeten Präteritums benutzt. Die Bedeutung ist exakt dieselbe.

Im Englischen ist das Perfekt hingegen eine Gegenwartsform. Aber Deutsch mit englischer Grammatik, das wäre doch etwas komisch, oder?

Comment: Das Present Perfect als Gegenwartsfort zu bezeichnen ist etwas irreführend, denn es wird für Handlungen benutzt, die zumindest in der Vergangenheit begonnen haben.

Comment: Das ist die übliche Definition im Englischen. Deshalb heist es ja auch **present** perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Der erste Satz

> Meine Katze hat mich immer so glücklich gemacht.

ist vollkommen normales, adäquates Deutsch, allerdings in der mündlichen Ausdrucksweise. Aus dem Umstand, dass Vergangenheit verwendet wird, schließt der Hörer, dass die Katze den Sprecher zum Sprechzeitpunkt nicht mehr glücklich macht, also verschieden ist oder sich davongemacht hat.

In schriftlichen Kontexten gewisser Komplexität (etwa in einem Roman) würde es eher heißen

> Meine Katze machte mich immer so glücklich.

Hier käme es dann auf den Kontext an, ob man als Hörer annähme, die Katze sei noch da und verbreite beim Sprecher Glücklichsein oder die ganze Geschichte liege vollkommen im Vergangenen.

Der Satz

> Dieser Mann hat sich in dieser Stadt etabliert.

könnte sowohl in mündlicher Sprache vorkommen (und Vergangenheit in irgendeiner Form meinen), oder aber auch in schriftlichen Ausdrucksformen, etwa in einem internen Polizeireport; dann aber mit der spezifischen Bedeutung, dass der Mann nach wie vor in der Stadt ist und dort den Zustand der Etabliertheit genießt. Wohingegen ein Satz wie

> Der Mann etablierte sich in dieser Stadt.

dann verwendet werden würde, wenn es um die Erzählung eines Ablaufs von Ereignissen ginge, wobei der Vorgang "Mann etabliert sich in Stadt" einer davon wäre, und zwar einer, der in der Vergangenheit läge. Ob der Mann noch in der Stadt weilt (oder dorthin gegangen ist, wo auch die Katze ist) kann man dem Satz allein nicht entnehmen.

Möchte der Autor des Polizeireports hingegen ausdrücken, dass der Mann zum Zeitpunkt des Schreibens (soweit man weiß) nicht mehr in der Stadt weilt, würde er - sofern er des Deutschen und seiner temporalen Differenzierungen mächtig genug ist - schreiben:

> Der Mann hatte sich in der Stadt etabliert.